# Best way to drop a field from a content type

Tags: 7, entities, hooks, updating

What is the best way to remove a Drupal 7 field from a content type defined via the GUI? I want to use hook_update_N so the changes can be propagated to multiple servers upon running update.php. However I cannot seem to find a solution. db_drop_table() would make sense to me for custom defined schemas, but not for a content type/field defined through the GUI.

Comment: you created a custom module to define a content type?

Comment: iStryker: created the content type via the admin interface, added some fields, then exported via Feature. But now I want to remove one of those fields programatically.

Comment: Noted that D5 provides a [content_field_instance_delete()](http://api.lullabot.com/content_field_instance_delete) function, documented [here](http://drupal.org/node/101742) and [here](http://drupal.org/node/620322), but that function is not available for D7. Also it is curious what field.install in D7 core uses to delete a fields: _update_7000_field_delete_instance() - a custom "internal" function that is not available for others to use. For something so important as fields, it seems to me that there should be a "public" function available somewhere, and that's what I'm searching for.

Comment: Currently my "candidate" public function is field_delete_instance().

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two api functions to delete fields:

- [`field_delete_field`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_field/7) To delete the entire field (all instances of of the field)
- [`field_delete_instance`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_instance/7) To delete only an instance of a field - which is how it's attached to an entity.

If you don't want to reuse the field, it might be a bit cleaner to delete the entire field instead of only delete the instance of it on the content type in question. Only you can be the judge of that.

Comment: Worked like a charm. The function does not return any arguments, so when using in combination with a hook_update_N() I would recommend doing a watchdog() to log your update changes.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, [field_delete_instance()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_instance/7) is the function to delete field instances.

Note that `field_delete_instance()` automatically calls `field_delete_field()` if there are no remaining instances, so `field_delete_instance()` is most likely all you'll ever need.

`_update_7000_field_delete_instance()` is designed for core update functions.
 Example: in update function `x_update_7000()`, you are using `field_delete_instance()`. Then in `x_update_7001()`, you change the `{field_config}` table in an inconsistent way and `field_delete_instance()` obviously needs to be changed as well.

But now `x_update_7000()`'s call to `field_delete_instance()` would result in an error because the table is still in the old structure. However, the situation for contributed modules is different, since they should always be executed *after* all core updates and therefore need to work with the most recent core version.

But, this is a pattern that you might want to use for your own API functions which you are using in update functions.

Additionally, these _update functions do not execute hooks because the outcome is not predictable (for example because the module for which the update is run might be disabled).